# Why is nano-meter technology not used to jam more coils into incandescent light-bulbs as done with semiconductors?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, nanoscience

Why is nano-meter technology not used to fit coils into incandescent light-bulbs?

I know we use nano-meter technology to fit more transistors into a small area on a silicon chip, but why do we not use that technology to fit more coils into an incandescent light-bulb to manufacture brighter light-bulbs?

Comment: There are people who nano-patterned  the filament with a femtosecond laser and that potentially improves the efficiency since it improves amount of visible light that is emitted. But it is too expensive to use. There are LED lighting systems where many smaller LEDs are used instead of a single large one, but usually not because they want to improve the efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of power that a tungsten lightbulb filament dissipates in the process of producing light is gigantic compared to the power being dissipated in an integrated circuit full of transistors. To prevent the tungsten filament from blowing up, it must be of a certain minimum thickness. That thickness is gigantic compared to the thickness of a trace in a chip which connects two transistors together and so the miniaturization trick that enables nanoscale IC's can't be applied to the design of tungsten lightbulb filaments.

Furthermore, at the temperatures at which tungsten filaments operate (thousands of degrees K) the tungsten traces on a silicon chip would destroy the chip itself in an instant.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the following.

For semiconductor technologies (specifically classical cpu architectures) the compute speed is proportional to semiconductor density on a mostly 2d chip. The only way to increase that is with smaller semiconductors.

For a simple light bulb the technological metric is optical power per electrical power. Adding more densely packed windings would increase light output per volume but each new coil would also increase electrical power consumed. There would be no gain in light power per electrical power. For that it’s better to move to a different electrical to optical conversion mechanism such as, for example, LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

Filament lifetime is limited by evaporation of the tungsten. If you make the filament thinner, the lifetime is reduced. I believe this is true even for halogen bulbs, which recycle the evaporated tungsten, since the recycling process isn't perfect.